# Wifi connections lost on suspend

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I have a weird issue with my WiFi connection. Every time I suspend or shut down my computer, the network becomes unavailable. This only occurs on my computer (phone WiFi works just fine), on this particular network (I can connect to my home WiFi).

After a lot of attempts, I usually manage to get it back, but it usually takes about 1 hour.

I tried all of the wlan0, eth0, service network-manager commands, none worked.

This might come from the fact that we use WiFi extenders, which might cause a conflict (2 routers are in range, both with the same name)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with you. Sometimes I can't connect to the network after my laptop is suspended.

I typically restart the network with this command:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Hope it helps.